# Create Button with toggle and text with a single element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button out of a single html element. The button needs to have a toggle slider and the text needs to be aligned vertically and horizontally. So I thought I can make use of `:before` element to help me make that happen. Here is what I have tried:

```css
div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Value</div>
```

I have 2 problems with the above code:

1. I can't position the text how I want and I have tried using text-align and position to move it around.
2. I am using a float, which means that it will affect behavior of other elements around it, and I really don't want that.

Is what I want possible with a single element?

Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m3q5Lcjy/

EDIT: The centered text should not be centered on the whole element, but on the light gray area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do this:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.toggler')).forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    item.classList.toggle('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 140px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: padding .25s ease;
}

.toggler.active {
  padding: 0 24px 0 0;
}

.toggler:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* transition to make it look smoother */
  transition: left .4s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.toggler.active:before {
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggler">Text Value</div>
<hr />
<div class="toggler active">Text Value realllllyy long</div>
<hr />
<div class="toggler">Text Value really far too long for this tiny, tiny, ohhh so tiny button. I recommend using shorter text though, but it won't break not even if you have like 10 or more lines.</div>
```

If anything about this implementation is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Your solution answers my question in full, however one part I forgot to mention and I am wondering if possible is that the text which is centered, can it be centered within the remaining space. Space of the light gray area as oppose to the whole element?

Comment: I read your new requirement already and the thing you need to do is adjust the padding according to active/non-active. Edited my answer.

Comment: The answer is above and beyond of what I was looking for. Thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for the idea to create such an element! The only thing I dislike is the toggle covering the text during the transition.

Comment: Added a solution for that (which requires and additional `span`).

Comment: I'm ok with that problem as its a very quick slide, nobody will notice imo. In my mind what would make this thing perfect would be if it was without javascript and I think it could be achieved with a checkbox element maybe instead of a div?

Comment: Yes, easy to achieve with a checkbox and a label. Should I add that?

Comment: No, the checkbox cannot have textual content - an thus, no `::before`.

Comment: Yeah if you can think of how to do it sure, please add it as I think I would use that instead.

Comment: Would you mind asking a new question for that and take my current code as base of your question?

Comment: Sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054712/remove-the-javascript-from-toggling-a-button

Comment: I just realized there is a big problem with this solution. If the text doesn't fit on one line, due to line height it gets pushed down below the button. Any way around this?

Comment: Not without introducing another element. You can prevent the wrapping using `.toggler { white-space: nowrap; }`.

Comment: The other solution is to not limit the width of your button by replacing `width` by `min-width`.

Comment: I think I have to break 1 element rule. If I add a span inside the div, how would you center that span?

Comment: That makes it alot more complicated due to your requirement of "centering in remaining space".

Comment: If it was without the remaining space?

Comment: `.toggler span { max-width: calc(100% - 48px); position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }`

Comment: I think I have a solution with 1 element thanks to hungerstar. https://jsfiddle.net/yaxvrrxL/7/

Comment: You`re getting there! :D

Comment: Added that flex solution to the code. Now replace `height: 36px;` by `bottom: 2px;` and set `.toggler { min-height: 40px; }` instead of `height: 40px;`and it will work for any number of lines. :D

Answer (score 3):

Use flexbox to center your text vertically and horizontally. Then use absolute positioning on your pseudo element. Make sure parent element has relative positioning applied so absolute positioned pseudo stays within the parent.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 24px; /* 20px for :before width, 4px for :before offset */
  
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Value</div>
```

Comment: You have a float in the `div:before` is that still needed now that you used flex?

Comment: Nope. Forgot to remove. Updated. Flexbox won't matter much since the pseudo element is absolute positioned.

Comment: Your solution answers my question in full, however one part I forgot to mention and I am wondering if possible is that the text which is centered, can it be centered within the remaining space. Space of the light gray area as oppose to the whole element?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Add some padding to the left side and do one of the following: 1) add `box-sizing: border-box` to `div` so the padding is a part of the width definition or 2) subtract the padding amount from the width for `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the text in a paragraph.

```
<div class="thediv">
    <p class="theText">
    enter text here
    </p>
</div>



.thediv{
Your own style.
}

.theText{
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
```

I don't see why you would want it be in one element.
If you do want that, you should give the div a padding.

```
div{
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 70px;
}
```

Comment: That would now be 2 elements, I am trying to find a solution with just 1

Comment: Add padding to the div?

Comment: You changed your answer after I added the comment. But if I add the padding, how do I find the center for the text and how do I get rid of the floating problem?

Comment: Finding the center of the div is going to be tough, unless it is going to stay this width. Just inspect the element in the browser, you will get the width of the div there, and you can devide it by two.

Comment: There's no reason this cannot be one element with a pseudo element. Finding the center is not that tough.