# Remove the javascript from toggling a button

Tags: html, css

Here is the code that currently toggles a button. I would like to remove the javascript component of it by maybe using a checkbox. The only requirement I have is that I have to use a single html element to accomplish this.

Here is the code sample:

```js
document.querySelector('.toggler').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* new styles here: */
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: padding .25s ease;
}

.toggler.active {
  padding: 0 24px 0 0;
}

.toggler:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* transition to make it look smoother */
  transition: left .4s ease;
}

.toggler.active:before {
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggler">Text Value</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3bfzagpm/2/

Can I accomplish this with `<input type="checkbox" class="toggler">Text Value</input>` Instead?

EDIT:

To be more specific what I want, I would like to have the toggle of the button without any javascript component to it. This should only be CSS and HTML. I would also like to maintain only 1 html element to accomplish this.

Comment: You mean you want a CSS/HTML only solution?

Comment: Be very specific about what you want, since this is almost identical to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49053077/215552)...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Updated, hows that?

Comment: You cannot as setting the `input` to checkbox will hide its value. You will at least need a label to display the.. well, 'label' for your button. Otherwise a toggle like on iOS or android is perfectly possible using `:before` and `:after elements`, one acting as background and one as toggle with the `:checked` pseudo selector to change where the toggle is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in your previous post, it cannot be achieved with only a checkbox because a checkbox cannot have `content`, and thus, no pseudo elements `::before` or `::after`, since both operate on `content`.

```css
.togglerCheckbox {
  display: none; }

.toggler {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  color: #FFF;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* new styles here: */
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: padding .25s ease;
}

.togglerCheckbox:checked + .toggler {
  padding: 0 24px 0 0;
}

.toggler:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* transition to make it look smoother */
  transition: left .4s ease;
}

.togglerCheckbox:checked + .toggler:before {
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="togglerCheckbox" /><label for="mycheckbox" class="toggler">Text Value</label>
```

Comment: Id is not needed right? I don't see it being used and Basically you are saying its not possible with a single HTML element, it has to have a second?

Comment: `id` on checkbox and corresponding `for` on label is what makes it work. It makes clicking the label check/uncheck the checkbox. Otherwise you would have to wrap the checkbox in the label, but then you cannot select *upwards* to react on `:checked` pseudoselector.

Comment: A checkbox _can_ have :before and :after elements, actually, it just cant display text content from the input itself (aka its value). Technically, with the upcoming `attr()` spec you could display it using `attr(value)` but I think thats a bit to... forward thinking for todays web right now.

Comment: No, it cannot. There are browsers that allow this, but this is against the specs and should not be used as e.g. Firefox does not allow it (which is correct). Regardless of that OP needs text on their button.

Comment: It's also part of the HTML standard that labels either have a `for` attribute referring to the `id` of the element they label, or the label should wrap the element. However, the technique shown here wouldn't work with a label which wrapped the element. Hence, the `id`.

Comment: How else should a browser know which element is being labelled by the label.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, you can try below option 
CSS:

```
#toggle:checked + .toggler:before{
  left: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />
<div class="toggler">Text Value</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aqMbym